# Stopping the Spark Streaming job after some time

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

Is there some way to kill the spark streaming job after some time, so the driver is not lost and rest API show the job as completed.

Comment: If you need to stop it, it's probably not right for Spark Streaming

Comment: I know that it's not a good practise but I need as I want metrics for memory usage and Dr Elephant needs a completed job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout function in `awaitTerminationOrTimeout(timeout: Long)` with your choice of `timeout` value will resume the execution of your main program after the timeout expires.

We will need to have some other wait function after that to keep the spark context alive for examination.

Something like:

```
// create streaming context
// do dstream stuff
streamingContext.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(streamingTimeout)
streamingContext.stop(stopSparkContext = false)
Thread.sleep(afterStreamingTimeout) // keep alive for some time.
// the end
```

As an alternative, you could use an interactive environment, such as a notebook, for those kind of experiments. There you can stop the context manually, by issuing `streamingContext.stop(stopSparkContext = false)` and the spark context will still be alive for as long as the notebook is active.  (This is what I use to prototype)

Comment: @JSR29  PS: Example of an interactive exploration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3TjGjffs3g&t=99s  (Not streaming, but the concept is analogous)

Comment: @JSR29 this might be a better example of interactive exploration with Spark Streaming: https://youtu.be/qxsOjJnwcKQ?t=526